# Magento End of Life for 1.7 versions?

Tags: magento-1.7

I came across that recent SUPEE 8788 patch is not released for Magento versions below 1.5. I read on forums that end of life for 1.x versions is in 2 years (end of 2018). But already early versions of Magento: 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 are not supported with recent security patch.

Does that means that with next few SUPEE updates Magento will cut out security updates for 1.5 , and 1.6 , and 1.7  versions?

Or it safe to assume that 1.7 will be supported until the end of life? Moving to 1.9 makes no sense as too little time left.

Answer (score -1):

as per my analysis you should upgrade to Magento 1.9 latest version. My point of view for Magento 2 is that it will unable to replace Magento 1.9 properly within the next two years because still Magento 2 has lots of bugs and many other minor issues. Whereas, Magento 1.9 version is more stable and more reliable to work with security. If you are looking to focus more on the stability factor, opt for Magento 1.9 but if you are looking for a future-ready store then you should definitely go with Magento 2.0 as errors and bugs will be sorted out with each update.

Comment: I am more concerned whether 1.7 will stop receing supee patches in the next year or so... or they will support it until the end of lie of 1.x version